# AngularJs doesn't display css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a little problem with my angularJS code, I'm trying to display json that contain css and html code. All that display on my website is a hardcode form html+css(it looks like the code below), i tired to use an ng-bind-html/ng-bind-html-unsafe, but it only displays html, and css code just dispensary. The easiest way would be convert displayed text to a code, but i don't have any idea to do this.

[image: CODE]

Comment: your css is in <style> tag?

Comment: no, it's in the style for each element in html just like above

Comment: the capture of image given, didnt see well

Comment: <p>asdsa</p> <ul> <li><span style="font-family: 'arial black', sans-serif;">asdsa</span></li> <li>d<span style="font-size: 24pt;">sad</span></li> <li>dsa</li> </ul> <ol> <li>asdsa</li> <li>adssa</li> <li>adsa</li> </ol> <blockquote> The whole code looks more or less like this

Comment: and the code is not compiled, and showed as raw content?

Comment: exactly, but i found already the solution, you just need to add one directive, that compile html with css, thanks for help!!! :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angularjs $compile service and do something like this in the controller-

First add a dependency to $compile in your controller and write below code

```
    myHTML = '<p></p>'; // your JSON data             
    $("#MyDiv").append(myHTML);
    var compiled = $compile(myHTML)($scope);
    $("#MyDiv").html(compiled);
```

It is not a best practice to do DOM manipulation in controller though and instead you can create a directive to do this.